# Progressive download of MP3 using MPMoviePlayerViewController behind .aspx page

Tags: iphone, asp.net, mp3, mpmovieplayercontroller, mpmovieplayer

i'm trying to enable progressive download of MP3 files we are hosting using MPMoviePlayerViewController in iOS 5. I can enable this using the code below when pointing directly to an MP3 file, but i wish to return them from behind an .aspx page so i can return a different file to the user based on certain parameters, as well as implement some additional security:

The objective c code:

```
NSString *urlString = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"http://someurl.com/stream_mp3.aspx?rec=%@", id];
NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:urlString];
player = [[MPMoviePlayerViewController alloc] initWithContentURL:url];
[self presentMoviePlayerViewControllerAnimated:player];
```

The code-behind (VB.NET) code for 'stream_mp3.aspx'

```
Response.Clear()
Response.ClearContent()
Response.ContentType = "audio/mpeg3"
Response.AppendHeader("Content-Disposition", "attachment; filename=" + fileName + ".mp3")
Response.TransmitFile(recordingPath & fileName & ".mp3")
```

Currently the player just opens and closes. The mp3 file returned from the page is fine and plays correctly when downloaded through a browser. I suspect it may be down to the file extension being .aspx and not .mp3, but i cannot change it else IIS won't process it. Does anybody know what I am doing wrong and if there a way to get this working, or another component that will enable me to achieve this?

Comment: Can you show the handler that is streaming the file?

Comment: Hi, do you mean the code for 'stream_mp3.aspx'? I have updated my answer with that code. Please let me know if I've misunderstood.